# WordPress does not set Cookies, Sessions or LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I try to set cookies or sessions with my own WordPress plugin.

My goal is that when I visit page **test.xy/page** and I am not logged in, that then a cookie is set, I am redirected to the login page and after successful login back to **test.xy/page**

Locally the plugin work, but nothing is set on my live system. Neither cookies/sessions via PHP, nor localStorage via JS.

**My try with PHP:**

```php
function redirect_after_login($redirect_to, $requested_redirect_to, $user)
{
    if (isset($_SESSION['redirect_to_test']) && $_SESSION['redirect_to_test']) {
        unset($_SESSION['redirect_to_test']);
        return home_url('/umfrage/');
    }
    return $redirect_to;
}
add_filter('login_redirect', 'redirect_after_login', 10, 3);

function redirect_non_logged_in_users()
{
    global $pagenow;
    if ('wp-login.php' !== $pagenow) {
        if (is_page('test') && !is_user_logged_in()) {
            $_SESSION['redirect_to_test'] = true;
            auth_redirect();
        } else {
            unset($_SESSION['redirect_to_test']);
        }
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_non_logged_in_users');
```

**My try withJS:**

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  if (
    window.location.pathname === "/test/" &&
    !document.body.classList.contains("logged-in")
  ) {
    localStorage.setItem("redirect_to_test", "true");
    window.location.href = "/wp-login.php";
  }
  if (
    document.body.classList.contains("logged-in") &&
    localStorage.getItem("redirect_to_test") === "true"
  ) {
    localStorage.removeItem("redirect_to_test");
    window.location.href = "/test/";
  }
});
```

Comment: Why are you even trying to implement the redirect logic yourself? `wp_login_url` can create a URL to the login page for you, and it takes a URL you want to redirect back to after the user's successful login, as optional first parameter.

Comment: wp_login_url just redirects me to wp-admin

Answer (score 0):

For using session in **WordPress**. You have to start it first.

Add below code in your **function.php**

```php
function register_my_session(){
  if( ! session_id() ) {
    session_start();
  }
}
if(!is_admin())
{
  add_action('init', 'register_my_session');
}
```

> If above code will not able to create sessions. Then try to disable the plugins. And recheck with updated WordPress version.